# After created custom theme in magento, list.phtml file is not working fine in Mobile App, when change product mode List/Grid?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am facing issues in **app/design/frontend/Abc/theme1/template/catalog/product/list.phtml** file for custom theme in Magento. I am creating **Mobile App** for my site.

When I am click on List/Grid/Pagination/Sort by option on product list page, then my custom theme file **app/design/frontend/Abc/theme1/template/catalog/product/list.phtml** is not called, It is called from my other custom theme **app/design/frontend/Abc/theme2/template/catalog/product/list.phtml** after change the **mode(Grid/List)**.

By default, When I open the app first time it will be called from **theme1 list.phtml** file, but after change the mode, it will be called from **theme2 list.phtml** file.

I have already created local.xml file for my **custom theme1**. 
This issue happen Only for **Mobile App**.

Why my list.phtml file is not working after change product **mode(List/Grid)**?

Please give me suitable solution for this issue ?